# Отправить письмо с анонимного адреса на gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, telnet

Стоит задача отправить письмо с анонимного адреса вида:

`<что-то>@spam.ru`

на адрес вида:

`<что-то>@gmail.com`

Сделать это необходимо посредством SMTP. Проблема в следующем: в универе есть по крайне мере 2 известных мне SMTP сервера. Пробовал отправлять с обоих, получается, но только на mail, yandex и прочие подобные, но никак не на gmail, туда просто не доходит, хотя пишет, что письмо отправлено. Решил отойти от этих сервером и попробовать через smtp самого gmail. Через 465 порт все работает, но письмо идет именно с моего уже существующего адреса. На 25 порту все хорошо до момента ввода самого текста письма и хедеров. В консоль ввожу следующее:

```
nslookup -q=mx gmail.com
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. 25
ehlo www
mail from: <test@spam.ru>
rcpt to: <моя-почта>@gmail.com
DATA
Subject: test
test
.
```

Мне выдает следующее сообщение: ***Messages missing a valid Message-ID header are not accepted.***

Пробовал добавлять уникальный, насколько это возможно хедер `Message-ID: действительно уникальный идентификатор`

Но ничего здравого не получаю, так же пишет, что идентификатор не валидный.

Что делать, как быть? Задание стоит отправить письмо именно с анонимного адреса заданного вида, препод ничего толкового не говорит, советов не дает, почту назначения менять не хочет.